# How do you install ECF DocShare on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install ECF DocShare on my computer, and I installed ECF from the marketplace, but when following this tutorial:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php?title=ECF/DocShare_Plugin&redirect=no
I found they had a "Share Editor With" tab that I don't, any suggestions?

Thanks,
 TehCosmicSloth